# TouchXML namespace resolving?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, soap

I am trying to parse the following XML via TouchXML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="namespace_1">
   <s:Body>
      <DefinedEntitiesResponse xmlns="namespace_2">
         <DefinedEntitiesResult xmlns:a="namespace_3" xmlns:i="namespace_4">
            <a:DefinedEntity>
               <a:Description>Some Description</a:Description>
               <a:Name>Some entity name</a:Name>
            </a:DefinedEntity>
         </DefinedEntitiesResult>
      </DefinedEntitiesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I try to parse this like so:

```
CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:[request responseString] options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

NSArray *resultNodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/s:Envelope" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Resultnodes: %@", resultNodes);
```

And getting the error:

```
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
XPath error : Invalid expression
```

Question 1: What am I doing wrong?
Question 2: Should I use TouchXML as a library, or is there something that works easier and better?

Comment: The TouchXML namespace handling can get tricky sometimes. You can use the libxml2 library (which TouchXML is a wrapper).

Comment: alternatively, you may try adding namespace definition that should go like this: `NSDictionary *nsmap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"namespace_1" forKey:@"s"];
[parser nodesForXPath:@"//s:Envelope" namespaceMappings:nsmap error:nil];  `

Comment: What is the best XML parser there is, i want my XML's to convert to good dictionaries eventually!

Comment: it depends on the features you need, desired performance and xml size. I recommend you to read this parser roundup: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project  (however, i've always settled with libxml2/NSXMLParser)

Comment: So what you are saying, TouchXML is basically the same as LibXML2, but only in objective C instead of C, NSXMLParser is event driven. Whatever this means!

Comment: I would like to save everything in my xml to dictionaries (recursive)!

Comment: Yeah, it is a objc wrapper of the c lib. If you are able to define the namespaces (look at the example i posted few comments above) TouchXML is good choice i guess.

Comment: I want the dictionaries generated dynamically, it means that namespaces changes all the time, so i can't really hardcode it!

Comment: got it. Why not create the dictionary by yourself using NSXMLParser? Or, check out this github project https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary

Comment: I was looking at this indeed, but it doesn't put it in a dictionary how it should!

Comment: Could you push me in the good direction for making this working properly, the thing is this XML-to-NSDictionary from this github project is not working properly when using deeper nested XML's!

Comment: how deeply nested are those XMLs you need to parse? and what's the issue with that implementation? any error code?

Comment: No error code, it makes dictionaries from everything but wrongly, it doesn't nest it well. At this moment i am trying to iterate trough a GDataXMLDocument, doesn't work so far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4150/discussion-between-wesso-and-mja)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following [project on github](https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name) to parse your XML into NSDictionary. You can then use `NSPredicate` to look up values in the parsed dictionary.